# Provisioning Profiles: Does the Device ask the prov embedded in the .app for UDID info?

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to clear up some confusion with provisioning profiles.

Say I have two provisioning profiles.

One contains this information:

```
AppID:   com.myCompany.testing.*
Devices: aaBB, ccDD, eeFF
Certs:   Dev1, Dev2
```

The other specifies this information:

```
AppID:   com.myCompany.testing.sampleApp
Devices: ggHH
Certs:   Dev1, Dev2
```

Now say I place the first prov on my test device, aaBB. Note that aaBB is specified in that prov.

Next, I build my app with the SECOND prov (note that aaBB is NOT in that prov). Can the device run my new build even though the second prov does not contain the device Identifier of the device? In other words, when a Device is deciding whether or not it can run an app, does it ask the app's embedded mobile provision whether its UDID is present?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Device `aaBB` wouldn't be able to run an app from the second provisioning profile.  I was running into this issue earlier today.  You need to add the device to the second provisioning profile.

Comment: That is what I thought. However, I just encountered this situation, and to my confusion, I found that the build did in fact run. When I jumped in to the build and examined the embedded mobile provision, I did not see the device's UDID listed. Maybe I am missing something. Can anyone else confirm this answer?

Comment: Really?  Odd.  I was running into this exact issue earlier today where I had a device added on the wrong provisioning profile and wasn't able to build to the device until I added it to the correct provisioning profile.